# Mod_rewrite .htaccess subdomain but differentiate between clean subdomain and pathed URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wildcard, subdomain

How do I mod_rewrite (in .htaccess) to do this?

```
{subdomain}.thedomain.com
```

OR

```
{subdomain}.thedomain.com/
```

...... should be rewritten as :

```
thedomain.com/index.php?do={subdomain}
```

.... HOWEVER all other files or directories should be rewritten without the subdomain part and the rest kept as-is.
        e.g.

```
xyz.thedomain.com/something/somethingelse/somefile.jpg
```

----------->

```
thedomain.com/something/somethingelse/somefile.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your subdomains *point to the same document root as the main domain*, all you need to do is add these rules to the htaccess file in the document root.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.thedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://thedomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.thedomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?do=%1 [L]
```